# perl: force the use of command line flags?

Tags: perl

I often write one-liners on the command line like so:

```
perl -Magic -wlnaF'\t' -i.orig -e 'abracadabra($_) for (@F)'
```

In order to scriptify this, I could pass the same flags to the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Magic -wlnaF'\t' -i.orig
abracadabra($_) for (@F);
```

However, there's two problems with this.  First, if someone invokes the script by passing it to perl directly (as 'perl script.pl', as opposed to './script.pl'), the flags are ignored.  Also, I can't use "/usr/bin/env perl" for this because apparently I can't pass arguments to perl when calling it with env, so I can't use a different perl installation.

Is there anyway to tell a script "Hey, always run as though you were invoked with -wlnaF'\t' -i.orig"?

Comment: Perl re-scans the #! line no matter how it was called.

Comment: Yes, but then it won’t do much once you’ve `chmod +x`’d it.

Answer (score 4):

You're incorrect about the `perl script.pl` version; Perl specifically looks for and parses options out of a `#!` line, even on non-Unix and if run as a script instead of directly.

> The `#!` line is always examined for switches as the line is being
>   parsed.  Thus, if you're on a machine that allows only one argument
>   with the `#!` line, or worse, doesn't even recognize the `#!` line, you
>   still can get consistent switch behavior regardless of how Perl was
>   invoked, even if `-x` was used to find the beginning of the program.

(...)

> Parsing of the `#!` switches starts wherever `perl` is mentioned in the
>   line.  The sequences "-*" and "- " are specifically ignored so that you
>   could, if you were so inclined, say
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> #! -*-perl-*-
> eval 'exec perl -x -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
>     if 0;
> ```
>
> to let Perl see the -p switch.

Now, the above quote expects `perl -x`, but it works just as well if you start the script with

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl                                                   -*-perl -p-*-
```

(with enough characters to get past the 32-character limit on systems with that limit; see `perldoc perlrun` for details on that and the rest of what I quoted above).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `#!env perl -...`, and `env` ended up being helpful:

```
$ env 'perl -w'
env: ‘perl -w’: No such file or directory
env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines
```

So, just modify the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env -S perl -...`

Comment: What version of `env` is that?

Comment: Linux env. GNU/Linux, I guess

Comment: Specifically my version of GNU/Linux `env` (env (GNU coreutils) 8.25) does not print the line "env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines".

Comment: That's... strange. The oldest `coreutils` I can find is 8.30 (Ubuntu 20.04), and `env 'perl -w'` still prints out that hint